# Android emulator takes time to run application

Tags: android

When I am running my hello world codes with Android emulator, its take more time to run. If it take more time my debugging process goes slow, because each time I have to run emulator. Is there a way which I am missing, or emulator takes more time to run applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not close the emulator during your development. Keep it open. It takes much time in first loading. Just leave it as is and continue to develop/debug.
You do not need to close the emulator and run it again each time.

Comment: But when I am keeping it open, then after editing some line of code ( Output must be change ), output remains same, how I can be able to see edited output.

Comment: Are you not saving your edits and starting new debug from menu or toolbar or F11? Me and all the people I know do in this way and we see the change to take effect immediately.

Comment: ok I done, using Run > run history > myAndroidApp. This reflects changes immediately. Are you saying about another way?

Comment: I use "Run > Debug", rather than Run History. 
So, your problem is solved?

Comment: Actually I hit the F11 key which is the shortcut for Run > Debug (at least in Windows version of Eclipse)

Comment: I am using Linux fedora, where F11 or ctrl+F11 gives same output. Anyway I got solution. Thank you for help.